# search in object react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In react I have an object which looks like

```
{
 {name: 'Colombia', code: 'CO'},
 {name: 'Comoros', code: 'KM'},
 {name: 'Congo', code: 'CG'},
...}
```

I need to search there for element which a user is typing(I am getting it from an input field). After every letter written by a user, I need to compare it with all names and find all names with that part

Comment: That's not an array, its a nested object. It's also invalid syntax.

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: So is it an array or nested object?

Comment: Can you give an example of the actual object? What you have posted is still not a valid object

Comment: @RobM. it looks like this.
{name: 'Comoros', code: 'KM'},
  {name: 'Congo', code: 'CG'},
  {name: 'Congo, The Democratic Republic of the', code: 'CD'},
  {name: 'Cook Islands', code: 'CK'},
  {name: 'Costa Rica', code: 'CR'},
  {name: 'Cote D\'Ivoire', code: 'CI'},
  {name: 'Croatia', code: 'HR'},
  {name: 'Cuba', code: 'CU'},
  {name: 'Cyprus', code: 'CY'},

Comment: So I have an object where are all counties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `filter()` and `includes()`

```js
let a = [{
    name: 'Congo',
    code: 'CG'
  },
  {
    name: 'France',
    code: 'FR'
  }
];

document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  let val = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
  let matches = a.filter(v => v.name.toLowerCase().includes(val));
  console.log(matches);
});
```

```html
<input id="foo">
```

Comment: I am already getting the output text this.state.value can you modify the code and can I use it in class ?

Answer (score 5):

Filter the contents based on the search string like

```js
var data = [{name: 'Comoros', code: 'KM'}, {name: 'Congo', code: 'CG'}, {name: 'Congo, The Democratic Republic of the', code: 'CD'}, {name: 'Cook Islands', code: 'CK'}, {name: 'Costa Rica', code: 'CR'}, {name: 'Cote D\'Ivoire', code: 'CI'}, {name: 'Croatia', code: 'HR'}, {name: 'Cuba', code: 'CU'}, {name: 'Cyprus', code: 'CY'}]

var search = 'om';
var filterData = data.filter(item => item.name.includes(search));
console.log(filterData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have accidentally used curly braces `{}` instead of brackets `[]` to denote an array in your question, and assuming you can use ES6 features, you can use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`String.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes):

```
// countries = your array
// Assuming you put the user input in a state variable called this.state.search = the user input string
var matchingCountries = countries.filter(element => element.name.includes(this.state.search));
```

If you use this in your component's `render` function, and render the resulting `matchingCountries` array somewhere, the component will be reactively updated as the `this.state.search` is updated.

Answer (score 0):

I've taken the liberty of correcting your data types:

```
data = [{name: 'Congo', code: 'CG'}, ...]
```

because the version you provided will only throw errors.

```
let data = [{name: 'Congo', code: 'CG'}];

...

handleKeyPress = (event) => {
    var value = this.event.target.value.toLowerCase(),
        matches = data.filter(function (item) {
            return item.name.substring(0, value.length).toLowerCase() === value;
        });
    
    console.log(matches)
}
render: function(){
     return(
         <div>
           <input type="text" onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress} />
        </div>
     );
}
```

Sorry, my react skills are really sub-par, so there's probably a better way to access the value of the input, than `event.target.value`.

Comment: unfortunately using your code I am getting an error can you look at the code ? https://github.com/ArmenSan/reactSearch
and the error is 
ERROR in ./js/app.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (35:17)

> 35 |   handleKeyPress = (event) => {
     |                  ^
  36 |     var value = this.event.target.value.toLowerCase(),
  37 |         matches = data.filter(function (item) {
  38 |             return item.name.substring(0, value.length).toLowerCase() === value;

Comment: why we need function after render ?